# Using Moq To Test An Abstract Class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, moq

I am trying to run a unit test on a method in an abstract class.  I have condensed the code below:

Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class TestAb
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("method has been called");
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[Test]
void Test()
{
    var mock = new Mock<TestAb>();
    mock.CallBase = true;
    var ta = mock.Object;
    ta.Print();
    mock.Verify(m => m.Print());
}
```

Message:

```
Method is not public
```

What am I doing wrong here?  My goal is to test the methods inside the abstract class using he Moq framework.

Comment: Did you see this thread? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604721/how-to-test-a-method-in-an-abstract-class-with-abstract-methods

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The message is because your `Test()` method is not `public`. Test methods need to be `public`. Even after making the test method `public` it will fail as you can only verify `abstract`/`virtual` methods. So in your case you will have to make the method `virtual` since you have implementation.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to mock methods on an abstract class like this, then you need to make it either virtual, or abstract.

Answer (score 3):

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66117999/959779) for the similar question :

As a workaround you can use not the method itself but create virtual wrapper method instead

```
public abstract class TestAb
{
    protected virtual void PrintReal(){
            Console.WriteLine("method has been called");
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        PrintReal();
    }
}
```

And then override it in the test class:

```
abstract class TestAbDelegate: TestAb{

     public abstract override  bool PrintReal();
}
```

Test:

```
[Test]
void Test()
{
    var mock = new Mock<TestAbDelegate>();
    mock.CallBase = true;

   mock.Setup(db => db.PrintReal());

    var ta = mock.Object;
    ta.Print();

    mock.Verify(m => m.PrintReal());
}
```